# SwiftUI ActionSheet how can i change cancel color

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-actionsheet

I have an action sheet that has 5 elements and a cancel button. I am trying to make the cancel button color red but it is not working. I have seen this one [SwiftUI ActionSheet different color for each action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62995678/swiftui-actionsheet-different-color-for-each-action). The destructive button style makes the other tabs red but do not know how to make it red for the cancel tab. I have updated my cancel tab to the following but the color is still Blue, any suggestions would be great.

```
.cancel(Text("Cancel")
.font(.system(size: 40.0))
.foregroundColor(Color.red))
```

This below is my code for the ActionSheet:

```
.actionSheet(isPresented: $showLocationOptions) {
    ActionSheet(title: Text("Which city/town is this place in ?"), message: Text("Select a location"), buttons: [

    .default(Text(location1)) {  },
    .default(Text(location2)) {  },
    .default(Text(location3)) {  },
    .default(Text(location4)) {  },
    .default(Text(location5)) {  },
    .cancel(Text("Cancel")
    .font(.system(size: 40.0))
    .foregroundColor(Color.red))
    
    ])
}
```

Comment: SwiftUI doesn't provide a public API to change each buttons' color on  an `ActionSheet` or `Alert` - probably for UI/UX concerns. I also suggest not to change colors on `ActionSheet` or `Alert`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No explicit way, but as workaround you can just use destructive style for explicitly named cancel button with nop action, like

```
.actionSheet(isPresented: $showLocationOptions) {
    ActionSheet(title: Text("Which city/town is this place in ?"), message: Text("Select a location"), buttons: [

    .default(Text(location1)) {  },
    .default(Text(location2)) {  },
    .default(Text(location3)) {  },
    .default(Text(location4)) {  },
    .default(Text(location5)) {  },
    .destructive(Text("Cancel")){       // << keep as last
            // just nop - will be just closed
        }    
    ])
}
```